# Custom widgets flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am new to flutter. Is there someone who can tell me which class to use to make a circular slider in dart in which we can get the value, change color, etc. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might follow along with this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svxUUz5mi9s - part of it includes creating a circular slider.

Comment: Is there a github for that ?

Comment: Here are more type of circular progressbars try this https://github.com/zmqgithub/circular_progress